# A simple create user statement fails?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

Like before, making `Java-Oracle11g-JDBC (OJDBC)` code. Java code tries to do an `executeUpdate()` on the statement below and an error occurs. But Oracle 11g executes it without any problems(via its GUI).

Statement-

```
 CREATE USER Person identified by 2012;
```

Error (ie A part of PrintStackTrace) -

> ```
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
> ```

Comment: Did you try removing the ';' at the ending? Is 2012 the password? If so, try escaping this with ''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't like the semicolon at the end. You don't want semicolons in your OJDBC queries, eventhough it works from the Oracle GUI.

Comment: That is very strange. The GUI of oracle 11g likes semicolons. Some java-sql statements use semis successfully, then why does it complain in the above case ?

Comment: @sweetdreams Yeah, something like JDBC->MySQL is fine with semicolons. But Oracle's JDBC won't allow multiple queries and I guess it outright considers `;` to be an illegal character. I don't have an explanation why that's the case.

Comment: @sweetdreams The reason why semicolon is being used is to terminate a line so that compiler or the engine would know that this is the end of the statement. JDBC doesn't need semicolon inside the string (""). Regards